# How can i set permissions for every single user?

Tags: python, django

I need to set permission for example: if i have two users in my website and both of them have the right to write a post and they can delete or edit their posts. so, how can i set delete or edit button without make it are accessible by all users on the website just make it accessible by the user who's made the post

question_view.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} This Question Belong To User: {{ request.user }} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- Full Question View -->
    <div class="my_question">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="answer-question">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3 class="text-primary">{{ my_question.title }}</h3>
                            <span class="clock">1 hour ago</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="question">
                            <p class="">{{ my_question.question }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <span>{{ my_question.field }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Options e.g 'Edit, Comment, Delete etc...' -->
    <div class="options">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a data-showin=".my-form" class="showin">Comment</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                    <a href="">Edit</a>
                    <span>
                        <a href="">Like</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                        <a href="">Unlike</a>
                    </span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- Comment Text -->
            <div class="user-answer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        {% for comment in comments %}
                            <p>{{ comment }}</p>
                            <p>1 hour ago</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Comment Field -->
            {% include 'community/comment_form.html' %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

community.models

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
import django

CHOICE = [('Technology', 'Technology'), ('Computer Science', 'Computer Science'),
          ('Lawyer', 'Lawyer'), ('Trading', 'Trading'),
          ('Engineering', 'Engineering'), ('Life Dialy', 'Life Dialy')
]


class UserAsking(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICE, default='Technology', help_text='Add the field to describe what your question is about')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    userasking = models.ForeignKey(UserAsking, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

account.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

CHOICE = [('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female')]


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    overview = models.TextField(editable=True, blank=True, default='You have no an Overview yet')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='male', choices=CHOICE)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='You have no skills yet')
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/default-logo.jpg', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(receiver=create_profile, sender=User)
```

if you don't mind I need to explain that here... I have no idea about the files can i attach but i think if you understand what i need you can get me to help
Thanks a lot

community.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserAskingForm, CommentForm
from .models import UserAsking, Comment
from account.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse


@login_required
def user_asking(request):
    form = UserAskingForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserAskingForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            asking = form.save(commit=False)
            asking.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            asking.question = form.cleaned_data['question']
            asking.field = form.cleaned_data['field']
            asking = UserAsking.objects.create(userprofile=request.user.userprofile,
                                               title=asking.title,
                                               question=asking.question,
                                               field=asking.field)
            asking.save()
            return redirect('community:user_questions')
    else:
        form = UserAskingForm()
        return render(request, 'community/asking_question.html', {'form': form})

    return render(request, 'community/asking_question.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def user_questions(request):
    all_objects = UserAsking.objects.all().order_by('-title')
    if not all_objects:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>This page Have no any question yet</h1>')
    return render(request, 'community/user_questions.html', {'all_objects': all_objects})


def question_view(request, user_id):
    my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(pk=user_id) # question number e.g '1' for user 'medoabdin'
    comment_form = CommentForm
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(userasking__title=my_question.title)
    context = {'my_question': my_question, 'comment_form': comment_form,
               'comments': comments}
    # Add comment
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = comment_form(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.userasking_id = user_id
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect('community:question_view', user_id)

    return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', context)


@login_required
def delete_post(request, post_id=None):
    post_to_delete = UserAsking.objects.get(id=post_id)
    all_objects = UserAsking.objects.all()
    try:
        post_to_delete.delete()
        return redirect('community:user_asking')
    except:
        HttpResponse('something wrong')

    return render(request, 'community/user_questions.html', {'all_objects': all_objects})
```

Comment: `{% if post.userprofile.user == user %}` will check that the post belongs to the user (assuming `user` is your `request.user`).

Comment: it doesn't work??

Comment: What’s the variable name for your post in your template? And is user defined in your context? (Does `if user.is_authenticated` work?)

Comment: Show us the rest of the template

Comment: i edit my post you will see the views file and full question_view file

Comment: But question_view is **already** showing the question for a specific user (you pass a user_id). If this is only supposed to show the question of the current logged in user, why don’t you check in the view that user_id == request.user.id? And if this should be show to **any** user then in your template you can check `myquestion.userprofile.user == request.user`.

Comment: Also please only add the relevant view, all the other views aren’t relevant to your question.

Comment: I was feeling some confusion.. this answer looks like work thank u @dirkgroten

Answer (score 0):

In your view you should pass the object(e.g. post here) and the user who is requesting then in template code in for the edit link use an if statement to check if the author of the post is the user who is requesting:

```
{{ if user == userasking.userprofile.user }}
    <a href="">Edit</a>
```

Comment: You are right abot the first part. In second part why it does not work are you sure about the userasking.userprofile.user is set properly?